# On AWS SWF, what is the good approach to publish the user interface (html css js)?

Tags: user-interface, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

To start with, please be sorry, I just start developping applications on AWS and I have some question that could be easy for you but not really for me... But impossible to find any response about web integration of a java website on SWF...

I'm also a new user of the spring framework, I need to do some tutorials about it (or not? SWF documentation can be enough?). But my questions are  for those who have already passed time on it and can say what is the best aproach in my case. (And why?)

- What is the good approach in UI design to have a web based application with ui dynamic changes? (like content slide, menu, etc... the most scalable choice)

Having the view (GWT web interface running on Elastic Beanstalk for example, or a CloudFront PHP interface using a good MVC PHP Framework?) separated from the model running on SWF? All linked by the API's.

Or having my complete web application using Flow FrameWork and GWT? (or another technology? For now I chosed this even if I have to work tutorials too, but why not using the new Dart Google's solution?)

- What is the easiest approach to do it efficiently?

I understood the SWF logical approach, and I have all my project's architecture (so the scalable SWF Model) in my head, but clearly, if I want to add a new service in my project and if this service wants to get a list of existing objects (stocked in DynamoDB for example), i'd like to show this information easily because I already did it for this object.

And so, with a copy of the model on the PHP interface, I imagine I could associate methods to show this object, and so concentrate the PHP projet for showing my objects and start workflows with PHP (search and read-only?), and SWF to have a good working model launching those WF. Is it a good approach? Is there a PHP framework really adapted to do this? Rather, I do it on a non-swf java UI application?

Comment: amazon-swf is for Amazon "Simple Work Flow"

Comment: Yes, I know it. That is my question, when we use the Flow FrameWork (based on AWS SWF), we can create a workflow architecture, with domains and workflows, but I'm not able to find the good solution to connect the entire model with a good UI, to have a web interface. There is no documentation or explication about it, or I haven't yet found it.

So if you have already done it, how did you did it?

Sorry, my question isn't easy to formulate...

Comment: If we apply this architecture :
http://d36cz9buwru1tt.cloudfront.net/architecturecenter/AWS_ac_ra_web_01.pdf
but with SWF for application servers with Flow Framework based application, is it the good solution?

But i'd like to use JavaWeb interface... If I use an AWS Elastic Beanstalk web UI application connected with the AWS SWF application, is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what I was searching about. To connect an UI interface, we have just to use good classes of the SDKs :

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#i=AmazonSWF

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html

My question was really simple, but I wasn't able to understand the entire SWF architecture.

So the solution is to implement the application's MODEL-CONTROLER with the SWF Flow FrameWork, and after that, we can connect the VIEWs with any of the SDK to start workflows. We can also connect an Android or iPhone application easily with the good SDK.